# MATLAB/Octave: Calculate the sum of adjacent/neighboring elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Let's assume an exemplary matrix `A = reshape([1:20], 4, 5)`, which looks like this:

```
A =

1    5    9   13   17
2    6   10   14   18
3    7   11   15   19
4    8   12   16   20
```

Coordinates `i`, `j` point to one element of the matrix, where I want to calculate the sum of the four directly neighboring elements. So, with `i = 3`, `j = 2` my element contains `7` and I want to get `6 + 8 + 3 + 11 = 28`. For elements at the border, like `i = 4`, `j = 2`, the missing neighbor is ignored: `7 + 4 + 12 = 23`.

Right now, I have to make sure, the elements exist (to prevent "out of bounds" error) and then add the value to the result:

```
result = 0;
if (i - 1 >= 1)
  result = result + A(i - 1, j);
end
if (i + 1 <= size(A, 1))
  result = result + A(i + 1, j);
end
if (j - 1 >= 1)
  result = result + A(i, j - 1);
end
if (j + 1 <= size(A, 2))
  result = result + A(i, j + 1);
end
```

There has to be a faster (and more elegant) way, right?

Comment: You could always pad the array with zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2D convolution fits to this problem perfectly.  Use MATLAB's [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) function with a corresponding kernel:

```
kernel = [0 1 0 ; 1 0 1; 0 1 0];
result = conv2(A,kernel,'same');
```

For further information about 2D convolutions in MATLAB: [Tutorial on 2D convolution of images](http://matlabtricks.com/post-26/tutorial-on-2d-convolution-of-images)

Comment: actually, the implementation for 2D convolution in matlab is pretty fast.
according to my measurements: for matrices of size 10,000x10,000 and type double, the runtime is ~400ms. for matrices of size 1000x1000 its only 5ms.
so usually this should be fast enough.

Comment: and I'm glad that it helped :) if the problem is 100% solved and you don't have any more comments - please accept the answer (by marking the V sign). if there are anymore open issues - feel free to write them down.

Comment: 2 comments: 1. if you just need to calculate the neighborhood sum of a single pixel, than @beaker's suggestion is definitely better than calculating convolution over the entire image.  2. the 'same' flag handles padding issues automatically, so you don't need to worry about it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A` is the matrix and `i`, `j` are the coordinates, there are the following two ways to do this:

- Using 2D convolution

  ```
  A = reshape([1:20], 4, 5)
  B = conv2(A, [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0], 'same');
  result = B(i, j);
  ```
- Padding the matrix with zeros, which doesn't change the sum, but prevents "out of bounds" error:

  ```
  A = reshape([1:20], 4, 5)
  B = padarray(A, [1 1], 0);
  result = B(i, j + 1) + B(i + 2, j + 1) + B(i + 1, j) + B(i + 1, j + 2);
  ```